# Send RAW Azure Push Message

Tags: azure, mobile, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to send a raw push notification message from Azure to my mobile device through an Web API. Previously I made use of a toast message and I got that working just fine, but not so much with the raw message type. This is what I've tried so far in my web API, without any success:

```
var jObject = new JObject
{
    {
        "Body", pushMessage.Body
    },
    {
        "From", pushMessage.From
    },
    {
        "Date", DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    },
    {
        "Title", pushMessage.Title
    },
    {
        "TargetType", pushMessage.TargetType.ToString()
    }
};

Notification notification = new WindowsNotification(jObject.ToString());
notification.Headers.Add("X-WNS-Type", "wns/raw");
notification.ContentType = "application/json";

var task = Notifications.Instance.Hub.SendNotificationAsync(notification, "some tag value");
```

The above code never pushes the actual message. Could someone please provide me with some information regarding this. I've tried various methods described on the web, without any success.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the above code works just fine - there was an issue with one of the settings in Azure ... pretty stupid mistake in the end o_O